# How to use a PHP associative array as function call arguments?

Tags: php, parameter-passing, associative-array, function-call

Assume that there is a function with some parameters and I have an associative array (or a simple object with public properties - which is almost the same, since I can always use a type cast `(object)$array`) whose keys correspond to the function parameter names and whose values correspond to function call arguments. How do I call it and pass them in there?

```
<?php
function f($b, $a) { echo "$a$b"; }
// notice that the order of args may differ.
$args = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
call_user_func_array('f', $args); // expected output: 12 ; actual output: 21
f($args); // expected output: 12 ; actual output: ↓
// Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:
// Too few arguments to function f(), 1 passed
```

Comment: You should show a code example of what you are trying to do

Comment: @JohnConde i'd love to, but the problem is that i donno how to do that in php . i've added a sample - not working though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, I just had to use variadic function named param unpacking feature introduced in PHP 8 ( https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params#variadic_functions_and_argument_unpacking ) :

```php
f(...$args); // output: 12
```

Prior to PHP 8, this code produces the error: `Cannot unpack array with string keys`.

Secondly, it turns out that `call_user_func_array` also works as expected in PHP 8 (see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params#call_user_func_and_friends for explanation):

```php
call_user_func_array('f', $args); // output: 12
```

- while it still outputs incorrect '21' in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

As a hack for older versions of PHP you could also use Reflection:

```
<?php
function test($b, $a) {
  echo "$a$b";
}

$callback = 'test';

$parameters = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];

$reflection = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
$new_parameters = array();

foreach ($reflection->getParameters() as $parameter) {
  $new_parameters[] = $parameters[$parameter->name];
}

$parameters = $new_parameters;

call_user_func_array($callback, $parameters);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1366fc0459cf75adf106da0b3def123135b0c579)

Comment: yeah, i've thought of this as well, but it looks a little bit overcomplicated for seemingly such a simple thing. but for older php versions it's probably the only working solution. but i think it's too much and maybe is a sign that one rather shouldn't use passing parameters as an assoc.array at all than use it with reflection, imo

Comment: That is why I noted `As a hack`. I also do not like this solution. But it's really weird that till now it was impossible to use associative array for `call_user_func`